# Ограничение поля и добавление 100 случайных маркеров Google Maps SDK Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, google-maps-api, google-maps, sdk

Передо мной стоит задача показать 100 случайных маркеров на ограниченной зоне. Зона должна примерно равняться карте Украины (Карту с координатами границ прикрепляю к вопросу). По кнопке Refresh , 100 старых маркеров удаляются , и появляются новые 100 маркеров в случайных местах. Маркеры не должны указывать место , их задача рандомно появиться и исчезнуть по refresh.

Мой VC:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var googleMap: GMSMapView!
    
    
    @IBAction func refreshButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition(latitude: 50.450001, longitude: 30.523333, zoom: 6.0)
        googleMap.camera = camera
        self.showMarker(position: googleMap.camera.target)
    }

    func showMarker (position: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = position
        marker.title = "Kiev"
        marker.snippet = "Capital of Ukraine"
        marker.map = googleMap
    }

}
```

[image: Координаты зоны:]

Карта с координатами (извиняюсь за неаккуратность)

Чисто теоретически , нужно задать площадь и показать маркеры через рандомайзер (мне советовали) , но на данном этапе обучения для меня это сложная задача , которую я пытаюсь решить. Надеюсь на помощь более опытных коллег , заранее спасибо за любую помощь!

Comment: как вариант - запустить цикл, и рандомно сгенерировать координаты в пределах вашего квадрата, и дальше вызывать метод передавая туда рандомные данные

Answer (score 0):

Так же как добавлена метка функцией `showMarker` добавить случайные 100.

Сгенерировать случайные координаты в нужной области вот так:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double.random(in: 45...51), longitude: Double.random(22...40))
```

При рефреше старые удалять, новые циклом добавлять:

```
func refresh() {
    for _ in 0..<100 {
        showMarker(position: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double.random(in: 45...51), longitude: Double.random(22...40)))
    }
}
```

Ещё можно добавить чтобы названия случайные делать и т.п. для красоты.

Comment: К сожалению , данное решение не подходит , в целом не работает. Так же просит исправить синтаксис в некоторых моментах , я исправил , но все равно не работает. Тем не менее , спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @user425843 , не добавляются маркеры или что именно происходит? Сейчас нет возможнлсти собрать и проверить. :(

Comment: Маркеры точно не добавляются) Ну а пока они не добавляются , проверить ограниченную зону я не могу :(